# Where do I configure spark executors and executor memory of a spark job in a dataproc cluster?

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I am new to GCP and been asked to work on dataproc to create spark application to bring data from source database to Bigquery on GCP.
I created a dataproc cluster with the following options:

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create testcluster \
--enable-component-gateway --bucket <bucket_name> \
--region <region> \
--subnet <subnet_name> \
--no-address \
--zone <zone> \
--master-machine-type n1-standard-4 \
--master-boot-disk-size 500 \
--num-workers 2 \
--worker-machine-type n1-standard-4 \
--worker-boot-disk-size 500 \
--metadata 'PIP_PACKAGES=pyspark==2.4.0' \
--initialization-actions <some_script.sh> \
--image-version 1.5-debian10 \
--project <project_name> \
--service-account=<account_name> \
--properties spark:spark.jars=<jar_path_of_source_db_in_bucket>,dataproc:dataproc.conscrypt.provider.enable=false \
--optional-components ANACONDA,JUPYTER
```

I am submitting a spark job in the below way:
[image]

What I don't understand is how do I specify the number of executors and executor memory?
Could anyone let me know where and how can I specify the parameters `--num-execuors` & `executor-memory` to my spark job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass them via the [`--properties`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataproc/jobs/submit/spark#--properties) option:

> `--properties=[PROPERTY=VALUE,…]`
> List of key value pairs to configure Spark. For a list of available properties, see:
> https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#available-properties.

Example using `gcloud` command:

```sh
gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark path_main.py --cluster=$CLUSTER_NAME \
--region=$REGION \
--properties="spark.submit.deployMode"="cluster",\
"spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled"="true",\
"spark.shuffle.service.enabled"="true",\
"spark.executor.memory"="15g",\
"spark.driver.memory"="16g",\
"spark.executor.cores"="5"
```

Or if you prefer to do it via the UI in the `Properties` section by clicking on `ADD PROPERTY` button :

[image]

Comment: Do I use `spark.executor.instances` to set number of executors which is equivalent to --num-executors ? . One last doubt. If I have to change these parameters for every spark job, what is the best way to apply these parameters ? Do I identify one optimum configuration for all kinds of jobs (heavy load and smaller loads) and then apply that to my cluster while I create it ?

Comment: @Metadata (1) yes. (2) It's hard to identify one configuration for all jobs in practice. It's preferable to set the properties for each job. at least if you're sure the jobs require the same resources you can submit them with the same config.